# Rails 3 ActiveRecord Sort on Computed Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sorting, activerecord

What I have is a named scope that is called in a Class method. An additional sort is done on the Array.  What I want to do is do the named_scope and sort in a single step.  The attribute that I am sorting on is not a column in the database it is a computed value. What I need is the oldest transaction in a "Created" status.

```
scope :transactions_in_created_status,
      where('trnsts in (?) and regsam = ?', 'Created', TYPE)

def self.oldest_transaction_in_created_status
  result = Transaction.transactions_in_created_status.sort{|a,b|         [a.update_date,a.update_time] <=> [b.update_date, b.update_time]}           
  result[0] 
end
```

I tried exactly what is posted below, but I get the ODBC error "update_date" not found.
def update_date
  converts a mmddyy  to ccyymmdd
end

Answer (score 1):

```
scope :transactions_in_created_status,
      where('trnsts in (?) and regsam = ?', 'Created', TYPE).order('update_date DESC, update_time DESC')
```

Then to get 1 you can just call first:

```
Transaction.transactions_in_created_status.first
```

Comment: Thanks for your help and suggestion.  I'm still running into difficulties in using the .order on the calculated fields.

Answer (score 0):

```
scope :transactions_in_created_status,
  where('trnsts in (?) and regsam = ?', 'CREATED', TYPE) do
    def oldest
      sort{|a,b|[a.update_date,a.update_time] <=> [b.update_date, b.update_time]}.first      
    end
  end
```